# Extend X axis interval ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, overlap

I am trying to plot data with lot's of X axis values. I am trying to not overlap my point with geom_point. I found lot's of discussions about "scale_x_continuous", "position = jitter or dodge" etc... and every time my problem is remaining because I need to keep my point aligned. Moreover, "scale_size_area" does not make it good.

EDIT: Generated data already melted at the end of the post.

I can not post image ([Link to image](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=646938Capturedcran20150909161830.png)), but to give the idea: I have 6 levels in my Y axis, and 400 levels in X axis. My points (shape = 1 = circle) are Y-levels aligned, and have different diameters depending on the value.

[image]

This is ok, but circles are overlapping.

```
plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x_variable_400_levels, y_variable_6_levels)) + 

        # value*100 because values are between 0 and 1 to have bigger circles
        geom_point(shape = 1, size = data$value*100) +

        # theme description
        theme(
              plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold", vjust=1),
              axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-0.5),
              axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=0.3)
        )
```

So, my question is: Can I modify the interval between two values of the X axis in order to avoid the overlapping between circles? Jitter is not interesting here because the noise does not allow a good visualisation of data, including that when I tried to had only HORIZONTAL noise.

Any kind of solution, links or other tutorial to solve it will be appreciated.

EDIT : Generated data. Import with read.table, sep = "," and header = T. The point is that, I have very little circles and they are important too.

```
data <- read.table(text='"trf","sample","value"
                   36,"S1",0.143882104
                   38,"S1",0.025971979
                   47,"S1",0.016711593
                   56,"S1",0.027896069
                   67,"S1",0.025870577
                   93,"S1",0.07638307
                   100,"S1",0.022905895
                   102,"S1",0.019192547
                   104,"S1",0.018258923
                   107,"S1",0.005032219
                   114,"S1",0.028297368
                   123,"S1",0.007874848
                   131,"S1",0.024184004
                   36,"S2",0.115123666
                   38,"S2",0
                   47,"S2",0.00479275
                   56,"S2",0.029523128
                   67,"S2",0.030133055
                   93,"S2",0.044749246
                   100,"S2",0.032865979
                   102,"S2",0
                   104,"S2",0
                   107,"S2",0.013160255
                   114,"S2",0.052047248
                   123,"S2",0.007632445
                   131,"S2",0
                   36,"S3",0.179332128
                   38,"S3",0.046215267
                   47,"S3",0
                   56,"S3",0.070791832
                   67,"S3",0.050214857
                   93,"S3",0.074108014
                   100,"S3",0
                   102,"S3",0
                   104,"S3",0
                   107,"S3",0
                   114,"S3",0.081441849
                   123,"S3",0
                   131,"S3",0.100090456', header=T,sep=",")
```

Comment: you can post a link to an image that others can include for you.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example, including (generated or real) data and the code you use?

Comment: Completely right, sorry. Here is a link to see image sample: [link](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=646938Capturedcran20150909161830.png)

Comment: I added the image, but you need to provide *your data*.

Comment: Thank you jlhoward. I will edit the post to add a generated data to represent the real data set.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the message you want to convey? Why do youn want circles? What do the vertical lines in your image represent? (And please read up on how to provide a reproducible example, as your data doesn't match your code)

Comment: Sorry Heroic, I can not provide data that are not mine, so I give a sub-sample. 

I want circle because they want circle to represent the proportion of each value in the line. The aim of this graphic is to show the distribution of the column "trf" in all column "sample" by the value.

Comment: The added lines do not have to be taken in account. I used them to try a ggplot2 function.
These lines were used to say for example: for this length of trf, here is the value evolution in different samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think changing the interval is the solution, as your x-axis is numeric. It would be more difficult to interpret if the space between for instance 1 and 2 is larger that the space between 9 and 10. And if you would change all intervals to the largest circle, the plot would be too wide. I also imagine it would be very cluttered if you have more data, which makes it harder to see patterns. Maybe a (faceted) barplot is the solution? Allows for horizontal and vertical comparison, small values are visible and values are easily extracted and compared. Here's a start:

```
p2 <- ggplot(data, aes(x=trf, y=value))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_grid(sample~.) +
  xlim(c(0,150)) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you Heroka, your idea is great. I will try this on real data and propose it. However, I will looking for a little more about the circle, which I want to have without overlapping.
Thank you for your time and this other way to visualize data!

Comment: You're welcome. But think about how you want to accomplish non-overlapping circles on the very wide x-axis you would have. If you were to draw it with pen and paper, how would you fix the issue?

Comment: Hum, you are right, the only way I see is to separate data. As you did, or for example the first part of x-axis in one graphic and the second part in an other one... But it sounds like a bad idea. 
I will try to work starting on your statement, thank you!